# Can I use Angularjs2 (ES6) without nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, iis, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to use Angular.js2 (ES6) without node.js? I did pilot page in winter with Angular.js1, and it worked great. Now that we have 'go' from management for the project implementation with Angular.js, there is Angular.js2 with ES6 is in scene. It is guaranteed that IIS is our one and only choice and nodejs will not be used.

Comment: Where the hell did you pick up the term "EC6"? Or is that something you created on your own? Or is it just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, angular and node are orthogonal.

- node.js is a server-side javascript runtime
- angular is a client-side (browser) framework

Comment: Angular.js2 is using EcmaScript 5/6 or TypeScript. Will EcmaScript work on IIS without iisnode?

Comment: i might not be fully understanding your question but, basically, Angular runs in the browser and talks to the server (running IIS) via HTTP (e.g., ajax calls). On the server side, you could use any language that IIS can support.

Answer (score 0):

yes there wont be any issues working with angular2 and IIS.
just make sure how you handle the dependencies because most javascript frameworks make use of npm for dependency management